# Open JSON files in PhpStorm built-in web server

Tags: json, configuration, phpstorm, built-in-web-server

I try to create simple PWA in PhpStorm. I have 2 files:

- home.html
- manifest.json

File `home.html` contains link to `manifest.json`:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

When I open `home.html` using PhpStorm built-in web server I have error 404 for `manifest.json` in Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I can open `home.html` in browser from context menu:
[image]

but I haven't this option for `manifest.json`:
[image]

Can I configure built-in web server in PhpStorm to work with JSON or this is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by your URL (`href="/manifest.json"`): leading slashes tell the browser to resolve URLs from the web server root.
Internal web server  returns 404 when using 'absolute' URLs as it serves files from `localhost:port/project_name` and not from `localhost:port`. If you like your URLs to be resolved when hosting your app on the built-in web server, use URLs relative to current file (`href="path/relative/to/home.html/manifest.json"`)